# SQL LIKE operator not showing any result when it should

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I got a Vehicle table with lots of info but one of the columns being 'Owner' in a MSSQL table

But one of the owners i can't select when i use `LIKE` but can if i use `=`

'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter' is the owner (Yes there is a double space in both the table and the param)

So the param is:

```
DECLARE @Owners nvarchar(MAX) = 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter'
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE @Owners = Owner 
--This gave me all the correct results
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE @Owners LIKE Owner
--No result
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE @Owners COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS LIKE Owner COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS
--No result
```

I need to use LIKE because i need to be able to select a array of owners at once. So the original select statement look like this

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE ('|' + @Owners + '|' like '%|' + Owner + '|%')
--No result
```

Any Ideas?

**Edit:**
It all works fine the @Owners is 'Fredericia  Distributionscenter' but not 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter', Both of them is within the table.

Is the something work in the 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter' text?

Comment: Not sure what to say. Your first `LIKE` query should work. (by definition if `a = b` is true, then `a LIKE b` is true). Check http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6adc3/3 for proof.

Comment: You have some space character in end of your Owner field in Vehicle table. '=' operator skips trailin spaces.

Comment: @Arvo You are a god! There was 2 spaces after the text so it was: 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter  '. If you write it in an answer i'll accept it. And Thanks to everyone else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Promoted to an answer as requested.*

You have some space characters in the end of your Owner field in Vehicle table. '=' operator skips trailing spaces, 'like' operator doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

try interchanging the column and the parameter

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Vehicle 
WHERE  Owner LIKE '%' + @Owners + '%'
```

Comment: This works but gives me problems when @Owners is 'Silkeborg' because then i get all 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter' and 'Silkeborg' owners, when i only should have alle the 'Silkeborg'

Answer (score 2):

the following runs fine, I suspect a missing information

```
declare @t  table (
    owner nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @t values ('Silkeborg  Distributionscenter'), ('rzrzezer')

declare @owner nvarchar(max) = 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter'

select * from @t
-- two lines
select * from @t where @owner = owner
-- one line
select * from @t where @owner like owner
-- one line
```

still works with

```
set @owner = 'Silkeborg  Distributionscenter|another one'
select * from @t where '|' + @owner + '|'  like '%|' + owner + '|%'
-- one line
```

but fail if

```
insert into @t values ('Silkeborg  Distributionscenter|abc')
select * from @t where '|' + @owner + '|'  like '%|' + owner + '|%'
-- one line, you may expect 2 in this case consider using a many to many relation
```

Comment: You are right, the problem was after the text i the table there was spaces

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect. Write it like:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE Owners like '%' + @Owners + '%'
```

Comment: Whoops, - typo. `Owners` here should be `Owner`

Comment: This works but gives me problems when @Owners is 'Silkeborg' because then i get all 'Silkeborg Distributionscenter' and 'Silkeborg' owners, when i only should have alle the 'Silkeborg'

Comment: LIKE is designed to work in this way. If you need only 'Silkeborg' use '=' in place of LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Owners nvarchar(MAX) = '%Silkeborg  Distributionscenter%'

SELECT * 
FROM   Vehicle 
WHERE  Owner LIKE @Owners
```

Or you can pass a modified param too, this of use when passing params from front end

Comment: This can't be done with the SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE ('|' + @Owners + '|' like '%|' + Owner + '|%'). AND same problem as above "This works but gives me problems when Owners is 'Silkeborg' because then i get all 'Silkeborg Distributionscenter' and 'Silkeborg' owners, when i only should have alle the 'Silkeborg'"